# How can i get some value from other page js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two page: Header.js and Post.js. These pages is joined on main page  - Home.js. Post.js has button "Buy". This button creates variable with value 0 or 1. This value is saved on local storage with window.localStorage.setItem(). And I Want to take with value and give to Header.js. But when I do this value isn't updated avere time, when I click "buy"

How can I make this?

```
 window.localStorage.setItem('countcart',count);
  const sumCount = async () => {
    
    if(count === 0){
      setCount(Math.max(count+1,0));
    } else{
      setCount(Math.max(count-1,0));
    }
      
  };

<Button className={styles.buy} onClick={sumCount} variant="contained" endIcon={<ShoppingCartIcon  fontSize="small"/>}><div className={styles.buytext}>Buy</div> </Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want localStorage to update every time `count` is changed, you should wrap it with a `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  window.localStorage.setItem('countcart',count);
}, [count])
```

But, this doesn't auto-update the count value in the other component; to do that with localStorage you'd need to use the https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/storage_event

But, a better way for the other component to access `count` would be to declare `count` as a state in the parent component and pass its state to the `Header.js` and `Post.js` components, e.g.:

```
// App.js
function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useCount(window.localStorage.getItem('count'));
  useEffect(() => {
    window.localStorage.setItem('countcart',count);
  }, [count])
  return (
    <>
       <Header count={count} setCount={setCount} />
       <Post count={count} setCount={setCount} />
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: For what do I need setCount in Header?

Comment: `setCount` is how React knows that the count variable is changed; otherwise `Header.js` doesn't know that the `count` variable has been updated and it won't end up getting updated in the Header.js component.

Comment: Soory, I am junor in this language. I can't understand what's problem. Post.js says to me that setCount is not a function. Can ypu help me?

Comment: Could you send the full code of your `Post.js` component?

Comment: I posted my code like answer

Comment: Make sure you pass `setCount` as a prop when rendering the `<Post>` component (you might want to send that code too)

Comment: I added code from app.js. May be I don't uderstand

Comment: Yep, in your line `        <Route path="/posts/:id" element={<FullPost />} />
`, you should pass the `count` and `setCount` as props to `<FullPost />` like this: `<FullPost count={count} setCount={setCount} />`

Comment: I found my mistake! you were shure! thank you very much! You are gorgeous!

Answer (score 0):

```js
import {Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import Container from '@mui/material/Container';


import { Header } from './components';
import { Home, FullPost, Registration, AddPost, Login, PostsByTag, Account } from './pages';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { fetchAuthMe, selectIsAuth } from './redux/slices/auth';




function App() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [count, setCount] = useState(window.localStorage.getItem('countcart')? 0 :window.localStorage.getItem('countcart'));
  const isAuth = useSelector(selectIsAuth);
  React.useEffect(()=>{
    dispatch(fetchAuthMe());
    window.localStorage.setItem('countcart',count);
  },[count])
  
  return (
    <>
      <Header count={count} setCount={setCount}/>
      <Container maxWidth="lg">
        <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home count={count} setCount={setCount}/>} />
        <Route path="/posts/:id" element={<FullPost />} />
        <Route path="/tags/:tag" element={<PostsByTag />} />
        <Route path="/posts/:id/edit" element={<AddPost />} />
        <Route path="/add-post" element={<AddPost />} />
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
        <Route path="/register" element={<Registration />} />
        <Route path="/account/:id" element={<Account />} />
        </Routes>
      </Container>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Rating,IconButton, Button} from '@mui/material';
import clsx from 'clsx';
import {Link, useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom';
import DeleteIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Clear';
import EditIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Edit';
import EyeIcon from '@mui/icons-material/RemoveRedEyeOutlined';
import CommentIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ChatBubbleOutlineOutlined';
import ShoppingCartIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ShoppingCart';
import styles from './Post.module.scss';
// import { UserInfo } from '../UserInfo';
import { PostSkeleton } from './Skeleton';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchRemovePost } from '../../redux/slices/posts';


export const Post = ({
  id,
  title,
  createdAt,
  imageUrl,
  user,
  viewsCount,
  commentsCount,
  tags,
  children,
  isFullPost,
  isLoading,
  isEditable,
  count,
  setCount,
}) => {
  // const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  
  if (isLoading) {
    return <PostSkeleton />;
  }
  console.log(count);
  window.localStorage.setItem('countcart',count);
  const sumCount = async () => {
    
    if(count === 0){
      setCount(Math.max(count+1,0));
    } else{
      setCount(Math.max(count-1,0));
    }
      
  };

  const onClickRemove = () => {
    if(window.confirm('Do you sure want to remove post?')){
      dispatch(fetchRemovePost(id));
      navigate(0);
      
  }
 
  };
  return (
    <div className={clsx(styles.root, { [styles.rootFull]: isFullPost })}>
      {isEditable && (
        <div className={styles.editButtons}>
          <Link to={`/posts/${id}/edit`}>
            <IconButton color="primary">
              <EditIcon />
            </IconButton>
          </Link>
          <IconButton onClick={onClickRemove} color="secondary">
            <DeleteIcon />
          </IconButton>
        </div>
      )}
      {imageUrl && (
        <img
          className={clsx(styles.image, { [styles.imageFull]: isFullPost })}
          src={imageUrl}
          alt={title}
        />
      )}
      <div className={styles.wrapper}>
        <div className={styles.indention}>
          <h2 className={clsx(styles.title, { [styles.titleFull]: isFullPost })}>
            {isFullPost ? title : <Link to={`/posts/${id}`}>{title}</Link>}
          </h2>
          <div className={styles.ratingprice}>
                <Rating 
                    name="size-small"
                    value={2.5}
                    size="small"
                    precision={0.5}
                    readOnly 
                  /> 
                  <div className={styles.review}>12 отзывов</div>
          </div>
          <div className={styles.price}>1150 руб.</div>
          {children && <div className={styles.content}>{children}</div>}
          <div className={styles.postDetails}>
                  <ul className={styles.postDetails}>
                    <li>
                      <EyeIcon />
                      <span>{viewsCount}</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <CommentIcon />
                      <span>{commentsCount}</span>
                    </li>
                  </ul>

                  <Button className={styles.buy} onClick={sumCount} variant="contained" endIcon={<ShoppingCartIcon  fontSize="small"/>}><div className={styles.buytext}>Купить</div> </Button>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  );
};
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).